# homotopy direct limits

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$X$ is said to be the homotopy direct limit of the sequence of subsets $X_1\subset X_2\subset ...$ if the projection $\cup_i X_i\times [i,i+1] \rightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence.

The following is true:

Suppose $X, Y$ are homotopy direct limits of the sequences $X_1\subset X_2 \subset ...$ and $Y_1 \subset Y_2 \subset ...$ respectively. Then if $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and each $f|_{X_i}: X_i \rightarrow Y_i$ is a homotopy equivalence then $f$ itself is a homotopy equivalence.

My Question:  Does anyone know off the top of his or her head whether the map $f$ can be replaced by a sequence of homotopy equivalences $f_i: X_i \rightarrow Y_i$ where the resulting diagram is homotopy commutative (i.e. $(Y_i\subset Y_{i+1})\circ f_i$ is always homotopic to $f_{i+1}\circ (X_i\subset X_{i+1})$)? I.e. are the spaces still homotopy equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: Where i can learn this material? I have the same problem when reading Milnor's book [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806889/why-limit-map-induces-isomorphisms-of-homotopy-groups-of-all-dimensions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the spaces are still homotopy equivalent.

Your situation with homotopy direct limits is a special case of a *homotopy colimit* and the defining property of homotopy colimits is exactly what you're asking for. See, for example, Theorem 1.4 of Rainier M. Vogt's "Homotopy limits and colimits". Be warned, there is a lot to read and to prove in order to get to this result.

However, since you are interested only in directed systems we should be able to find a more direct (no pun intended) proof. At our disposal we have the homotopy equivalences between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ and the homotopies assuring associativity of our diagram. With these tools can you see a way of constructing a natural-looking continuous map between $\cup_i X_i\times [i,i+1]$ and $\cup_i Y_i\times [i,i+1]$? Can you construct a homotopy inverse?

I did the former part, but I failed to find the homotopy inverse. I hope you'll have more luck than me, though!

EDIT: See the comments for a discussion on how such a homotopy inverse might be constructed.

Comment: Thanks Roar!  I'm quite relieved. Yeah the obvious thing to do is $(x, t) \mapsto (f_i(x), 2t), 0\leq t\leq 1/2, (x,t) \mapsto (h_i(x,t), i+1)$ where $h$ is the homotopy between $\iota \circ f_i$ and $ f_{i+1} \circ \iota$.  I'll have to think about an inverse. Thanks very much.

Comment: some typos in my definition but I hope we have in mind the same map "move with double speed for half the interval and use the second half to homotope"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the map I had in mind, Tim! [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/46352/1823) to another question is related to our situation, but there the existence of a homotopy inverse is guaranteed by an algebraic argument.

Comment: OK I think that the same thing will work for an inverse, $G$ (I am basically just adapting the proof from the case where the $f_i$s are restrictions): If $g_i$ is an h-inverse to $f_i$ then in fact the "inverse diagram" is also h-commutative:  $\iota \circ g_i =_h g_{i+1}\circ f_{i+1} \circ \iota \circ g_i =_h g_{i+1}\circ \iota \circ f_i \circ g_i =_h g_{i+1}\circ \iota$.  Now if $X_{\Sigma} := \cup_i X_i \times [i, i+1]$ then I think $X_{\Sigma}$ is a h-direct limit of the spaces $U_i := \cup_{k\leq i} X_k \times [k,k+1]$.  And each $U_i$ def retracts onto $X_i \times {i}$ on which...

Comment: $G\circ F$ has the form $f_i \circ g_i$ which is homotopic to the $id|_{X_i}$.  And I think the same argument will show that $F\circ G|_{U_i}$ is also homotopic to the identity.  So if we invoke the proposition for the case when the $f_i$s are restrictions of some big $f$ we should get our generalization? Does this make any sense?

Comment: In hindsight its a pretty obvious adaptation (if its correct) but I probably wouldn't have had the confidence to look for it if I didn't know the statement was true :)

Comment: I believe you are correct. Your supposition that $X_\Sigma$ is a h-direct limit of the $U_i$ is at least valid. The space $X_\Sigma$ is in fact the direct limit of the $U_i$ and since all the inclusions $U_i \hookrightarrow U_{i+1}$ are cofibrations the direct limit and h-direct limit are the same. I will edit my answer and point the reader to your argument.